# Python function doesn't work in C API of Apache2.2

Tags: python, c, apache2

I have compile `mod_xxx.c` that is include python code.

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "ap_config.h"
#include "python2.7/Python.h"
static int r4_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    if (strcmp(r->handler, "r4")) {
        return DECLINED;
    }
    r->content_type = "text/html";      

    if (!r->header_only)
      { Py_Initialize();
        Py_Finalize();
        ap_rputs("\tPrint test\n", r);}
    return OK;
}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But don't print "Print test" on my web browser. `Py_Initialize();` `Py_Finalize();` functions not working?

Comment: You probably need to fill more the complex `request_rec` structure `r`.

Comment: How to fill complex request_rec? Now i know just this request.

Comment: I have no idea. Read more about Apache & python embedding